# Grayed out textfield unless checkbox ticked

Tags: java, swing, text

How, using `JTextField`, can I create my program to enable/disable a textfield depending on whether or not a checkbox is ticked?

I have an option which, if checked, needs to take input. If not checked, I'd like the text field to remain grayed out with the user unable to enter text.

Comment: Sure you can. Try to do that and if you fail post your code and we'll help you.

Comment: You add a listener to the JCheckBox, say an ItemListener, and then in that listener enable or disable the JTextField via its `setEnabled(boolean enabled)` method.

Comment: What is a "tickbox". I'm not aware of any Swing component by that name. Use the class names of the Swing components so there is no confusion on what you are talking about.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I'm sure Rob assumed the same, but we all run into trouble if we're forced to assume, which I think is the point he's trying to make. The original poster would do well to be as precise as possible in his question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Indeed. I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

mchq08 did not give a complete answer since his code will do nothing if the JCheckBox is unchecked.  You don't need the if block as all you'd need is a single line of code in your item listener

```
checkBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent itemEvent){
    // the line below is the line that matters, that enables/disables the text field
    textField.setEnabled(itemEvent.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that task with the check box with a simple if/else statement within an event listener.

You would want to put this into an event Listener for the check Box so when the event is fired it will allow it to editable. You could also go a step more and create another if/else if the check box is false and delete the text within the text box and set it to editable.

```
if(checkBox.isEnabled()){
   textBox.setEditable(true);
}
```

[Link CheckBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html)
[Link TextBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Checkbox.html)